# Display a title to players with a set scoreboard value!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I own a minecraft server and I am making a TnT run minigame all from command blocks for good experience working with CMD blocks.

So I wanted to basically display a title to the players in the minigame. So I decided to do this via a scoreboard. So when they get teleported to the arena, they have a value set to 1 on a scoreboard objective, I then want to display this title to the players with a value of 1.

How is this done?

Comment: You *may* have better luck over at gamedev.stackexchange.com. As this is *almost* out of the scope of this site as the question pertains to programming, then again since its mod development it *may* fall under this site.

Comment: @ColeBusby this seems to be a question on using Command Blocks which is on-topic here

Comment: I don't think you can set per-player scoreboard displays using command blocks. In vanilla, scoreboards set to display is displayed to ALL players on the server, unless you use the [`org.bukkit.scoreboard`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scoreboard/package-summary.html) library of methonds in a Bukkit plugin to manipulate it. As for scoreboards, try using `/scoreboard objectives display [location] [objective name]`.

Answer (score 1):

Create scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add inArena dummy
```

Run on clock to give people in the arena an inArena score of 1:

```
/scoreboard players set @a inArena 0
/scoreboard players set @a[x=<X>, y=<y>, z=<z>, dx=<X length>, dy=<Y length>, dz=<Z length>] inArena 1
```

To display the title to people with inArena of 1:

```
/title @a[score_inArena_min = 1] <Title>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Specification tag may be used.

```
/title @a[score_(ObjectiveName)_(min/max)] title {"text":"Insert Message Here"}
```

`[score_(ObjectiveName)_(min/max)]` is your Specification Tag, this can be used in many ways like specifying for a certain gamemode (`m=[0-3]`), being at coordinates (`x=[Insert X Coord.] y=[Insert Y Coord.] z=[Insert Z Coord.]`) to being in a certain range of a certain axis of those coordinates (... `dx=[Difference] dy=[Difference] dz=[Difference]`).